# split variable and add level in HTML tree

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, html-parsing, elementtree

I need to create the HTML (the file will actually have a ".nfo" extension, but it's an html file) that looks like this (called "MovieNFO.nfo"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<movie>
  <title></title>
  <sorttitle></sorttitle>
  <plot></plot>
  <thumb></thumb>
  <mpaa></mpaa>
  <genre></genre>
  <premiered></premiered>
  <actor>
    <name></name>
    <order></order>
  </actor>
  <art>
    <fanart></fanart>
    <poster></poster>
  </art>
</movie>
```

In my Python script, I used ElementTree to create the hierarchy:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(MovieNFO)
root = tree.getroot()
```

I have a variable (artist) that has a list of actor(s) for a given movie (for this example, let say the value of artist is "Jason Bateman, Kathryn Hahn, Allison Janney, Philip Baker Hall").  I can then populate the "Order" tag with a counter.

My code is currently:

```
if artist is not None:
    actorcount=0
    root[7][0].text = artist[1]
    root[7][1].text = str(actorcount)
tree.write(fullnfoname, encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Which gives me:

```
 <actor>
    <name>Jason Bateman, Kathryn Hahn, Allison Janney, Philip Baker Hall</name>
    <order>0</order>
  </actor>
```

What I want is:

```
 <actor>
    <name>Jason Bateman</name>
    <order>0</order>
  </actor>
 <actor>
    <name>Kathryn Hahn</name>
    <order>1</order>
  </actor>
 <actor>
    <name>Allison Janney</name>
    <order>2</order>
  </actor>
 <actor>
    <name>Philip Baker Hall</name>
    <order>3</order>
  </actor>
```

I think I need to split the variable "artist", but then I don't know how to add a new subkey (for the additional actors).  In other words, I got this is work because the one tag was already there.  How do I create more tags for the additional actors especially when I don't know how many there will be after I split?

Comment: What exactly is the input to this process? You parse something called `MovieNFO`. What is that? How is it related to the `artist` variable?

Comment: MovieNFO is the first file in the post (called MoveNFO.nfo) and I read it in with "tree = ET.parse(MovieNFO)".  I use ffprobe in the code to get the actors, movie title, etc that I need to put into the MovieNFO file.  That's where artist comes from.  When I parse the output of ffprobe, the code I use is: if line.startswith('TAG:artist='):    artist = line.split('TAG:artist=', 1)

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding comments. What is ffprobe?

Comment: I don't know how to close this question out.  I have solved my own problem.  Instead of trying to read and edit an HTML file, I'm just creating it from scratch.  Thanks for the help!